# How to prevent nausea/stomach ache during workouts

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, nutrition

I have been lifting for about 5 years now and every so often I get a churning stomach ache about 30 minutes into my workout (which consists of a 5-minute cardio warm up and then powerlifting exercises for the most part). I always workout in the evening after work and try to get in some sort of small meal beforehand for energy. I suspect that the issue stems from a hydration/electrolyte imbalance but I am not for certain. Can anyone recommend a pre-workout plan that includes what foods/drinks to consume to prevent nausea?

Comment: I will leave this open for a bit, but I don't think this is a good question. What works for persons A, B and C may not work for you. Your best bet is to figure out what you are doing/eating/drinking on days you get nauseous to see if there is a pattern.

Comment: I would classify this as a medical question, regardless of it being aimed towards physical exercise, simply because this sounds like an issue that needs a medical diagnose before any conclusions can be drawn. Anything else would be speculation, and unsuited for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "JohnP" commented, there's no perfect fit answer.

I will however mention that there are some that are generally known to cause nausea, heartburn, gas or other "gastro" related discomforts during a workout if ingested beforehand.

**Foods With:**

- high fiber
- high amount of fats
- legumes
- lots of spice (like Mexican or Indian food)

Answer (score 0):

For "me" its not eating a few hours before I go workout.  I teen to go hard in the gym these days and I notice, if there is food in me I feel 'ick' ...

What time of day do you eat vs going to gym?